# Switching back to a seat in Aveilut

Tags: minhag, synagogue, mourning-aveilus

There is a practice for a mourner to [change](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45147/do-mourners-change-their-seats-in-shul-today) his seat in Shul -- there are many different [opinions](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=130&article=433) about when and how.

If, during the period of mourning, the mourner suffers another loss, so he changes his seat again, can he change it back to the original location or must he move to a third space?

Comment: Who says that one who suffers another loss changes his seat again?

Comment: I don't understand why he would change again. He's already not in his designated seat

Comment: @rosends if the new place became his makom kavua he'd have to move from it even if no one new died. Moving is not a one time thing. He moves from his makom kavua every time he walks in.

Comment: @GershonGold the source I have says one would change a seat after A loss. It makes no distinction as to first, third or twelfth. The text cited, from Mode Katan, apparently reads "“A mourner, the first week..." but doesn't say "A mourner, the first time he mourns..." So why would there be an assumption that this rule only applies sometimes?

Comment: Can you please reveal your source?

Comment: @GershonGold the source is Moed Katan which indicates behavior when one is a mourner. What source do you have that says that the info in Moed Katan doesn't apply when a second person passes?

Comment: @DoubleAA then I don't understand "He moves from his makom kavua every time he walks in". If I sit in different spot consistently, wouldn't it become my makom? Are you saying that I would then have to move from IT also? (as per your statement "if the new place became his makom kavua he'd have to move from it even if no one new died") So he has to constantly find a different place because each place becomes his new makom.

Comment: @rosends no new place becomes his makom. If you move into a hotel during home construction/renovations, even for months at a time, your home never changes.

Comment: @DoubleAA so then if the place I move to is not my makom, but the original location is (no matter than I no longer sit there) then if another person passes, I need not move because by sitting in this temporary place I have already abandoned the singular place designated as my makom?

Comment: That's basically exactly what I said above.