# Public mourning in Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, mourning-aveilus

Why isn’t the custom of changing ones seat in shul considered mourning in public , which is prohibited in Shabbos?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45157/1362

Comment: Who said it isn't? Who said it's public?

Comment: Someone has to sit there, so how does one know that the mourner siting there is because of mourning? It is only by knowing that last year he sat somewhere else that we can give this any significance, so, apparently, this is not called public.

Comment: @Mord alternatively the custom was only practiced in places where people didn't have fixed seats but fixed areas. Changing your seat within your area wasn't noticable. Then some people with fixed seats didn't know better and kept it up inappropriately

Comment: @mordechai who said anything about last year? The person sits there everyone Shabbos and all of a sudden he is changing seats.